# Reload routing to home page in develop time (Angular, Nativescript)

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I have a problem in develop time.
When i do some changes in my code, HMR reload application and navigate to home page.
(In web angular, i stay at current page after reload page, when i add some code)

How can i fix it in my nativescript & angular app?

- I use page-router-outlet for routing.

Comment: Which version of CLI & Runtime you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the regarding part of NS blog:

- When you make a change, the webpack compiler is responsible for generating a 'diff' (hot update) between the old version of the bundle and the new one.
- The webpack development server handles the transportation logistics for HMR. In other words, it makes sure the hot update can be loaded when requested by the application. It's not mandatory to use webpack-dev-server for transferring the files. In the NativeScript ecosystem, the NativeScript CLI plays that role.
- A special code, injected into your application bundle, fetches the hot update. Then, it starts looking for handlers for each module, that should be replaced.
- **The module is replaced if an appropriate handler is found. If not, the process fails and the module is not replaced**. Obviously, it's good to have a fallback **in that case**. In the browser, the page is reloaded, and in NativeScript - **the application is restarted**.

Source: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/deep-dive-into-hot-module-replacement-with-webpack-part-one-the-basics